# gsub string for all spaces in Ruby 1.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8

I have a string with spaces (one simple space and one ideographic space):

```
"qwe　rty uiop".gsub(/[\s]+/,'')    #=> "qwe　rtyuiop"
```

How can I add all space-codes (for example 3000, 2060, 205f) in my pattern?

In Ruby 1.9 I just added `\u3000` and other codes, but how do it in 1.8?

Answer (score 2):

I think i found answer. In ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Chars is a UNOCODE_WHITESPACE constant. Solution:

```
pattern = ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Chars::UNICODE_WHITESPACE.collect do |c|
  c.pack "U*"
end.join '|'
puts "qwe　rty uiop".mb_chars.gsub(/#{pattern}/,'')
#=> qwertyuiop
```